# Column to flag the most max row of a group

Tags: python, pandas

With this code:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'car_plate':['1v','2f','3a','h0','m1'],
'car_brand':['Honda','Honda','Ford','Audi','Audi'],
'last_seen':['01/01/2020','01/02/2020','01/03/2020','01/04/2020','01/05/2020']})

data['last_seen'] = pd.to_datetime(data['last_seen'])
```

I have the following dataframe:

|  | car_plate | car_brand | last_seen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1v | Honda | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2f | Honda | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 3a | Ford | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 3 | h0 | Audi | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 |
| 4 | m1 | Audi | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |

I would like that for ever `car_brand`, I mark to `1` the row that have the most recent `last_seen`, so the output is:

|  | car_plate | car_brand | last_seen | recent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1v | Honda | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 1 | 2f | Honda | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 3a | Ford | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 3 | h0 | Audi | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 4 | m1 | Audi | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | 1 |

As the `2f` is the most recent Honda, `3a` is the most recent Ford, and the `m1` is the most recent Audi.

I've been thinking of this idea, pseudo code: group by `car_brand`, get max `last_seen`, get the index of that row, create a column `seen` and set to 1 those indexes.

P.S.: I'm also wondering how it would work if I add more levels to the combintion, e.g `car_owner`, and I would like the most recent `car_plate` + `car_owner` combination for every `car_brand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a temporary column, containing the last row per group, and then use a boolean mask to assign the 0s and 1s:

```py
last = data.groupby('car_brand').last_seen.transform('last')
data.assign(recent = data.last_seen.eq(last).astype(int))

  car_plate car_brand  last_seen  recent
0        1v     Honda 2020-01-01       0
1        2f     Honda 2020-01-02       1
2        3a      Ford 2020-01-03       1
3        h0      Audi 2020-01-04       0
4        m1      Audi 2020-01-05       1
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
data['recent'] = data.index.isin(data.groupby('car_brand')['last_seen'].idxmax()).astype(int)
```

To answer your question about adding more levels to the combination: yes, you can. Just change `'car_brand'` in the above code to `['your', 'columns', 'here']`, e.g.

```py
data['recent'] = data.index.isin(data.groupby(['car_brand', 'car_plate', 'car_owner'])['last_seen'].idxmax()).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
data['recent'] = data.groupby('car_brand').cumcount(ascending=False).eq(0).astype(int)
data
  car_plate car_brand  last_seen  recent
0        1v     Honda 2020-01-01       0
1        2f     Honda 2020-01-02       1
2        3a      Ford 2020-01-03       1
3        h0      Audi 2020-01-04       0
4        m1      Audi 2020-01-05       1
```