# Create a column to flag rows with largest values of their respective groups

Tags: python, python-polars

Given a polars dataframe with columns 'group' and 'value' create a new column 'group_max' to flag which records are the max of their respective group.

This can be achieved in pandas relatively straightforwardly

[Column to flag the most max row of a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70051051/column-to-flag-the-most-max-row-of-a-group)

Is it possible to do this in polars without first creating a separate grouped dataframe and then joining that dataframe to the original based on the 'group' and 'value' keys?

EDIT:
The following code works but creates an intermediary grouped dataframe

```
grouped = df.groupby('group').agg(pl.col('value').max()).with_columns(pl.lit(1).alias('value'))

df = df.join(grouped, on = ['group', 'value'], how='outer')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Window functions](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/window/)

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(dict(
   group = ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"], 
   value = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1]
))

df.with_columns(group_max = pl.col("value") == pl.max("value").over("group"))
```

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬───────────┐
│ group ┆ value ┆ group_max │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ str   ┆ i64   ┆ bool      │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════════╡
│ A     ┆ 1     ┆ true      │
│ B     ┆ 2     ┆ false     │
│ C     ┆ 3     ┆ true      │
│ A     ┆ 1     ┆ true      │
│ B     ┆ 4     ┆ true      │
│ C     ┆ 1     ┆ false     │
└───────┴───────┴───────────┘
```